# Передать в информацию на страницу webview в Android

Tags: java, android, input, android-webview

Ситуация такая: надо при переходе на страницу в Webview передать строку в поле.
Страница https://propusk.gosuslugi.ru/check_code
Поле там одно, но, как я понял, формируется скриптами.
Никак не могу понять, как можно это сделать.
Буду рад советам.

Comment: Я думаю, можно с помощью javascript сделать

Answer (score 1):

Надо найти имя вашего элемента и передать ему свою строку - примерно так:

```
final String myString="blah-blah"; //строка которую надо передать
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //elementName - JavaScript имя объекта
        view.loadUrl(
        "javascript:document.getElementById('elementName').value = '"+myString+"';");
    }
});
```

Comment: Самое обидное, что на той странице ни как не могу найти имя этого элемента, а так код рабочий для других страниц) спасибо.